# .NET Core worker exception: Value cannot be null. Parameter name connectionString

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, serilog, worker

I have created a .net core worker and installed it as a service. I have also implemented a Serilog logger in the worker. to log when the worker starts and closes. when running my worker in the debug mode it perfectly logs in MSSQL server Log table. but, when I publish the worker in the release mode and start the worker from the services, it does not log anything. It throws an exception: Value cannot be null. Parameter name connectionString. How can I fix this?

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "Server=localhost; Initial Catalog=context; User ID=ct; Password=ct",
          "tableName": "Log"
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  "AllowedHosts": "*",

  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost; Initial Catalog=context; User ID=ct; Password=ct"
  },

  "EnyimMemcached": {
    "Servers": [
      {
        "Address": "127.0.0.1",
        "Port": 11211
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Worker.Program.cs

```
public class Program 

{
        public static readonly stringenvironmentName=Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production";

        public static readonly IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .Build();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var iWebHost = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
                
                var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                    .CreateLogger();

                Log.Logger = logger;
                iWebHost.Run();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Log.Fatal(exception, "Error starting the service");
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<GameWorker>();
                    services.AddDbContextPool<IqSoftLiveCasinoContext>(optionsBuilder =>
                    {
                        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
                    });
                    services.AddEnyimMemcached(options => configuration.GetSection("EnyimMemcached").Bind(options));
                    services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
                    services.AddScoped<ICacheProvider, CacheProvider>();
                })
                .UseSerilog()
                .UseWindowsService();
    }
```

GameWorker.cs

```
public class GameWorker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<GameWorker> _logger;
        public IServiceScopeFactory _serviceProvider;

        public GameWorker(ILogger<GameWorker> logger, IServiceScopeFactory serviceProvider)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("GameWorker started at {time}", DateTime.UtcNow);
            return base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("GameWorker stopped at {time}", DateTime.UtcNow);
            return base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"Worker running at: {DateTimeOffset.Now}");
                await Task.Delay(10000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue falls in this line:

```
.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
```

You need to pass the directory in a different way, you may try using something like this:

```
var uri = new UriBuilder(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
var path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
.SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(path))
```

That's because of when you run it by VS it gets the exact context where you're running it from, but when it runs as a service `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` will get a system location instead of the one the application got deployed.

Comment: Is not really related to your connection string, is related to where it reads the config from.

Comment: I do not know how to thank you! it worked!! but isn't it that the content of appjson file is same in both directories?

Comment: No, the problem is because if for example you're running it in windows, then when you use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` that will get the `System` folder, and there your app.settings.json file does not exists, and it goes to that path because is running as a windows service